# Recording two simultaneous video feeds from webcams on Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: pi-4, webcam

I am wanting to have a Raspberry Pi 4 connected to two USB webcams recording at `720P` with `30FPS`.

Is this computationally possible with the specs of the Pi?

I am a little concerned about the data transfer but I think I read that Raspberry Pi 4 can channel two USBs to the CPU.

Comment: You might want to try out http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/Raspberry_PI_WebCam#MjpegStream to check this.